# How can I query FB to get admins of Facebook APP?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Is it possible to perform FQL or something else to get list of admins in particular fb app? As far as i am reading https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/application we can only get developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation at the [developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/developer) table suggests to use the [app_role](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/app_role) table. There you can query the field `role`, which can be administrators, developers, testers, or insights users:

```
SELECT ... FROM app_role WHERE developer_id = A
SELECT ... FROM app_role WHERE application_id = A
SELECT ... FROM app_role WHERE developer_id = A AND application_id = B
```